# Extra line in git -i rebase

Tags: git

What is the meaning of line 3 and 4 in the output of `git -i rebase`

```
pick adb6252 foo
fixup fc1386f fixup! adb62521234123412341234123421cb7df43ab7a
 f023b79b561bb071e18123456789abcde440cbb1 !
 ^f023b79b561bb071e189b367cba987654321cbb1 !
pick 0f440b5 bar
pick c4651ee foo bar
pick f023b79 fixup! ...
```

The `git log --oneline` before the rebase looks like:

```
f023b79 fixup! ...
fc1386f fixup! adb6252
c4651ee foo bar
0f440b5 bar
adb6252 foo
```

Is this related to the fact that I named it `"fixup! ..."`. (I chose `"..."` to remember to reorder it myself).

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. When using `--autosquash`, `git-rebase` expects the messages to match (up to the `squash!` and `fixup!` prefixes). Best use `--no-autosquash` and perform the reordering yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug because you used `...` as your `fixup!` note. The `git -i rebase` is a complicated script and it probably got unexpected output when searching for the first commit that matched `...`.